# jump to next server in the for each loop if pre checks fails

Tags: powershell

This is start of my script where I do some things to my servers. First I get servers from txt file and check that I have access to net share so can access the package needed and after that move forward using invoke command and script block

```
foreach ($server in (Get-Content .\myservers.txt)) {


# check access to net share

            if (test-path "\\mynetshare\package"){
                 write-host "I have access to net share on"  -ForegroundColor Green
               
            }
            else {
                write-host "I have not access to net share" -ForegroundColor Red
            }

# check the c:\temp
            if (test-path "\\$Server\c$\Temp"){
                 write-host "server has C:\Temp folders." -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            else {
                write-host "server has no  C:\Temp. Let's create one."
                New-Item -Type Directory "\\$Server\c$\Temp" -Force
            }

    Copy-Item -path \\mynetshare\package\package.msi -Destination "\\$server\C$\Temp" -Recurse
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {

my powershell script does magic

}

}
```

So what do I need to add / change of if I have no access to server (e.g Windows Remote Management (WinRm) problems) so it would not go forward from  `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock` part  but instead just jumps the next server in the list?

Comment: With `if (test-path "\\mynetshare\package"){..}` you are actually testing if **you** have access to that share. Nothing to do with the servers you are iterating..

Comment: Yea you right, I had thinked a bit wrong here. I edied my post so that if I have issues connecting to the vm it would not go forward with the scritp.  @Theo

Comment: Wrap the `Copy-Item` and `Invoke-Command` lines in a `try{..} catch{..}` block and append `-ErrorAction Stop` to both lines. Inside the catch{} block just output a warning and the code would proceed with the next server. Oh yeah, remove `-Recurse` since you're only copying one single file.

Comment: Yup, got it working ! :) Why should I remove -Recurse if only copying one file?

Comment: -Recurse is needed when you are copying files from a directory, including the files in subfolders.